# Netflix Zuul Not Passing Through Correlation Cookie for .Net Core 3.1 Web App - Identity Server 4 and Nginx

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nginx, identityserver4, netflix-zuul

I have a basic .Net Core 3.1 `mvc` web app that uses hybrid flow in conjunction with Identity Server 4 (based on their quickstarts).  The latter sits behind `nginx` and the web app sits behind `nginx` and `zuul`.  When I click the login button in the web app I get redirected to Identity Server's login page.  After I login, the `oidc` redirect fails and in my web app logs I have a correlation id cookie error stating its been lost.

What I did to then was put the web app directly behind `nginx` like Identity Server, and everything works as expected with the `oidc` login and logout redirects.

This is my `zuul` configuration in `application.properties`

```
zuul.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
zuul.ignored-services= '*'
zuul.add-host-header=true

server.port=9002
spring.application.name=zuul
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:9001/eureka}
zuul.strip-prefix=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

Is there something else I might need in this configuration to solve my problem?

My `nginx` is configured to forward all the necessary headers for the web app, but it is likely that something is getting lost downstream when proxying from `zuul`.

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://zuul:9002/;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
```

This is all done using Docker containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite a simple fix in the end, as I initially misinterpreted the `zuul` documentation.  What I am indeed doing above is blacklisting cookies:

```
zuul.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

It appears that `zuul` blacklists `Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorisation` out of the box.  As soon as I set the property to an empty string or a random string name, everything works as expected.